# Is the linker retained after a call to exec?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, android-source

I'm trying to watch the linker load libraries and search for symbols in zygote on Android.

Zygote is started by init (or a start/stop zygote command on the CLI). In the init.*.rc files, I've modified it to have an environment variable of LD_DEBUG=2 (via a setenv LD_DEBUG 2 in the init.zygote[32|64].rc file). In the linker code, this should print debugging information to logcat, which it does if you invoke a program from the command line, ie: "LD_DEBUG=2 ./myprogram".

However, this does not work for zygote. I took a look at /proc/[zygote's pid]/environ, and the LD_DEBUG=2 is definitely there.

The linker code for a service (among other things) sets up the environment array, calls fork(), does a little more work, and then calls exec() with the array it created.

So, I'm wondering, is there any way that the linker would be retained across this fork-exec? I didn't think that was possible, since I thought an exec completely wiped a process's memory space.

I could see how if it is retained, it wouldn't be invoked again, since the linker has already been loaded, but if it the process memory space is being wiped, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Every program that's dynamically linked (which is generally all programs) uses the linker as part of the process startup.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was invoked on initial startup. I was curious if it was retained in memory over a fork-exec, since that is what init is doing and I don't see it getting invoked again with my environment variable. However, I just proved to myself by writing a pair of programs that the linker is wiped and will be loaded into the memory of the child on exec.... Still not sure why I don't see this via the service calls in init.rc, but at least that mystery is over :)

Comment: I'm talking about the startup of the new program that's being exec'ed.

Comment: Every process normally executes `ld.so` as part of its startup.